# Footer section coincide with other division section using CSS

Tags: html, css

While designing a web page, I have used  tag to divide sections in a page. All the sections are working according to CSS I have written for the same, but the "last" div which is supposed to be a footer section of the page coincide with the upper division.
Can anyone help how to overcome this problem.
I have provided JSFiddle link here
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/165mk87q/4/)

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    #biggest{
        width:90%;
        padding-left:5%;
        padding-right:5%;
        height:auto;
    }
    #header{
        height:150px;
        background-color:#8888ff;
    }
    #menus{
        height:50px;
        background-color:#d9d9d9;
    }
    #threecols{
        width:100%;
        height:inherit;
    }
    #one{
        width:20%;
        height:auto;
        background-color:#0081c2;
        float: left;
    }
    #two{
        width:78%;
        height:auto;
        float:right;
    }
    #three{
        width:70%;
        height:auto;
        float:left;
        background-color:#3366FF;
    }
    #four{
        width:29%;
        height:auto;
        float:right;
        background-color:#ffffcc;
    }
    #last{
        width:100%;
        height:100px;
        background-color:#ffdddd;
    }
 </style>
<body>
<div id="biggest">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="menus"></div>
    <div id="threecols">
        <div id="one">
            This is one<br/>
            This is one<br/>
            This is one<br/>
            This is one<br/>
            This is one<br/>
            This is one<br/>
        </div>
        <div id="two">
            <div id="three">
                This is one<br/>
                This is one<br/>
                This is one<br/>
                This is one<br/>
                This is one<br/>
                This is one<br/>
            </div>
            <div id="four">
                This is one<br/>
                This is one<br/>
                This is one<br/></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="last"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i cant get ur question as per my assumetion  the `#four` have to come down?

Comment: last need to come down @vasanth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you expecting something like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/165mk87q/5/)**

**CSS**:

```
 #last {
        clear:both;
        display:block;
        width:100%;
        height:100px;
        background-color:#ffdddd;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

the container `#three` and `#four` are in float u need to clear thoes float element for the parent `#two`  same as u need to clear the `#threecols` . whereever u floating the div's u need to clear the parent div.
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vasanthanvas/3whurht0/)
HTML

```
<div id="biggest">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="menus"></div>
    <div id="threecols" class="clearfix">
        <div id="one">
            This is one<br/>
            This is one<br/>
            This is one<br/>
            This is one<br/>
            This is one<br/>
            This is one<br/>
        </div>
        <div id="two" class="clearfix">
            <div id="three">
                This is one<br/>
                This is one<br/>
                This is one<br/>
                This is one<br/>
                This is one<br/>
                This is one<br/>
            </div>
            <div id="four">
                This is one<br/>
                This is one<br/>
                This is one<br/></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="last">footer content</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    #biggest{
        width:90%;
        padding-left:5%;
        padding-right:5%;
        height:auto;
    }
    #header{
        height:150px;
        background-color:#8888ff;
    }
    #menus{
        height:50px;
        background-color:#d9d9d9;
    }
    #threecols{
        width:100%;
        height:inherit;
    }
    #one{
        width:20%;
        height:auto;
        background-color:#0081c2;
        float: left;
    }
    #two{
        width:78%;
        height:auto;
        float:right;
    }
    #three{
        width:70%;
        height:auto;
        float:left;
        background-color:#3366FF;
    }
    #four{
        width:29%;
        height:auto;
        float:right;
        background-color:#ffffcc;
    }
    #last{
        width:100%;
        height:100px;
        background-color:#ffdddd;
    }
.clearfix:after{
   content: " "; 
   visibility: hidden;
   display: block;
   height: 0;
   clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the div `#threecols`

[Updated Code](http://jsfiddle.net/165mk87q/6/)

Add `.clear` class

```
<div id="threecols">
        <div id="one">
            This is one<br>
            This is one<br>
            This is one<br>
            This is one<br>
            This is one<br>
            This is one<br>
        </div>
        <div id="two">
            <div id="three">
                This is one<br>
                This is one<br>
                This is one<br>
                This is one<br>
                This is one<br>
                This is one<br>
            </div>
            <div id="four">
                This is one<br>
                This is one<br>
                This is one<br></div>
        </div>

<div class="clear"></div><!--Add this-->
        </div>
```

**CSS for clear**

```
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```